# Angular 6 angular-cli build works, build --prod fails

Tags: angular, angular-cli

It is work fine when using `ng build` or `ng serve` but it is error when using `ng build --prod` with white blank and gives error

**uncaught Error: StaticInjectorError[t -> t]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for t!**

with **WARNING in Invalid property name ' filter' at 3032:2. Ignoring.** on console while building

Here is my **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { EasyUIModule } from 'ng-easyui/components/easyui/easyui.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { UserComponent } from './pages/user/user.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { MainComponent } from './layout/main/main.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './layout/login/login.component';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";
import { CookieService as SessionCookie } from "angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service";
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { GlobalService } from "./global.service";
import { UserService } from "./pages/user/user.service";

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    MainComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
  ],
  providers: [SessionCookie, CookieService, JwtHelperService, UserService, GlobalService],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    EasyUIModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ]
})


export class AppModule { 
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private global: GlobalService
    ){

  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. May not be dupe.  The other question the person is using Angular 5, not Angular 6.

Comment: Are all your services using in providedIn: 'root'?

Comment: unfortunately some of my service are located in subfolder, for some scalability reason

Comment: How are you providing them? That error would make it seem you are asking for a service that you are not providing anywhere in the injector tree.

Comment: If you aren't seeing the issue with ng-serve my guess is it's somewhere in a lazy loaded module.  If you hit that lazy loaded page or module you would see the error in the console when using 'ng serve'.

Comment: im sorry, im just starting to learn angular, so what should i do then?, i update my question to provide my appmodule.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't going to be enough to find the error.  I would need to see your entire application.  Is it a large application? Navigate to each of your routes when you 'ng serve' and monitor the console.  You will see the StaticInjector error except this time it will give you the full name of the service it can't find.

Comment: ok, ill try and will inform asap.but at least can you tell me, that i already provide every service i use?

Comment: Impossible to tell.  Problem is somewhere you are injecting a service in a constructor that cannot be found in the injector tree.  If you are only using singletons for services then you can use the new providedIn attribute instead of the providers array.  https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183337/discussion-between-ryan-e-and-ryan-arief).